# I have to wait until I arrive at the office for a cup of coffee. / I have to wait for a cup of coffee until I arrive at the office

Tags: relative-clauses

I've read the following sentence in my book:

> I **have to wait** until I arrive at the office **for a cup of coffee**.

Isn't there more logical to rewrite into:

> I **have to wait for a cup of coffee** until I arrive at the office.

What's the need to use the first version?

It's not easy talking like that, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think there's a *need* to use the first version, but it sounds more natural to this US English speaker.  Why would it be "not easy"?   "I have to wait until X" is a very natural phrasing.

Comment: @stangdon, For  non-native speaker it's quite difficult because you need to remember to say "for" after "office". It's easier to say "for" after "wait".

Comment: @stangdon, If I understand you correctly, the first version sounds better for you. Right?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but they both sound bad. "I have to wait until I get to the office to have a cup of coffee" is acceptable. When you wait "for" something "until" a certain time, it sounds like you're waiting to get that thing (like, for someone to give you the thing) *before* the given time.

Comment: @Sergei Yes, the first one sounds better.  The second one sounds like maybe you need a cup of coffee before it is possible for you to arrive at the office, although in practice everyone will understand what you mean.

Comment: @stangdon, It's a very interesting nuance. Maybe you know where it is possible to read
 about it. How can that topic be called in English? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I have to wait until I arrive at the office for a cup of coffee." This means that you cannot have coffee until you arrive at the office. (Sergei, per your comment, your version has exactly the same meaning: "I have to wait for a cup of coffee after arriving at the office.")

"I have to wait for a cup of coffee until I arrive at the office." "until" sounds a little strange here. Clearer phrasing would be to use "before" or "after." Each would tell me when you could have the coffee, "before" getting to work or "after" getting to work.

Comment: I guess the sentence "I have to wait for a cup of coffee after arriving at the office." has a completely different meaning in comparison with "I have to wait until I arrive at the office for a cup of coffee."